# Windows Server 2008 R2 ADUC - Naming information cannot be located

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-patching

I'm having a very hard time with Active Directory.

Brand new server with a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. Everything was fine until it restarted after installing updates.

When I try to access ADUC, I receive a message "Naming information cannot be located because: The network path was not found"

If I run dcdiag from cmd, I get:

```
Trying to find home server...
Home Server = CEMSA-AD
[CEMSA-AD] LDAP connection failed with error 0,
The operation completed successfully..
[CEMSA-AD] Unrecoverable LDAP Error 89:
```

I have checked DNS, it is all correct, nslookup resolves correctly.
LDAP is also running as I can connect to the LDAP server using Sysinternals AD Explorer.

Problem is, I cannot manage any users and groups at the moment.

Active Directory Administration Center works, but again, parts of it such as group memberships fail.

Comment: Have you tried rolling back your updates?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, is the problem with ADUC or ADAC? A patch in December broke ADAC and needs to be uninstalled to restore ADAC functionality.

The bad patches include KB 3205394 for Windows 7 and KB 3206632, KB 3205386 for Windows 10.

FMI: http://www.infoworld.com/article/3155264/microsoft-windows/december-windows-security-patches-crash-active-directory-admin-center.html

Answer (score 0):

Try following (Please make sure to back up your registry before doing this, Just to be on a safer side)

Start Registry editor (regedit)

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlset\services\ldap

From Edit Menu, Select New and enter String value

Type IPv4LoopbackAlternative, Then press enter

Now Right click on IPv4LoopbackAlternative, Click Modify and In ValueData box type 127.0.0.2, CLick Ok and exit registry editor. Restart and check. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Start Registry editor (regedit)

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlset\services\ldap

From Edit Menu, Select New and enter String value

Type IPv4LoopbackAlternative, Then press enter`
It's work. Thank you so much
But I close ADUC and start again it is not work