# Can't open Active Directory Users and Computers, although AD is operational

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

This is the error I'm getting when trying to open Active Directory and Computers on the Domain Controller:

```
Naming information cannot be located because: The network path was not found.
```

The NETLOGON service is running.

When I execute the command 'dcdiag', this is what I get:

```
Directory Server Diagnosis


Performing initial setup:

       Trying to find home server...

   Home Server = DC2012R2

   [DC2012R2] LDAP connection failed with error 0,

   The operation completed successfully..
   [DC2012R2] Unrecoverable LDAP Error 89:
```

I'm using Windows Server 2012 and am able to use Active Directory Administrative Center.

Any help would be much appreciated!

-Stijn

Comment: Did you check this post  http://serverfault.com/questions/626224/server-2008-r2-aduc-naming-information-cannot-be-located?

Comment: I did, but I'm worried about messing with my registry since nobody upvoted that comment.

Comment: 1. run netstat –a command to check if port 389 is listening; 2 restart DNS service and check again. 3 Test DNS server with nslookup